Does a message request a read receipt?
When accessing Gmail, is there any way to determine whether a message as read receipt requested?
This Q&A looks relevant, but it doesn't actually answer my question.  I'm actually unsure of what question it's answering.  It looks as if it is saying that the recipient may (or may not) be prompted before Gmail sends a read receipt, if one has been requested.
My question is more about determining whether a read receipt is requested, regardless of whether you (as the recipient) sent a receipt in the past.  So just looking that message, can you tell whether read-receipt is enabled?
I'm not sure, but it might be a 2-part question.  First is when you are looking at a message for which you are the recipient.  Second is if you are looking at a message for which you are the sender.  I don't know if the mechanism for determining enablement of read-receipt is the same for the two cases.
I tried selecting "Show original" for a message, which showed some cryptic header information, but a search for "receipt" turned up nothing.
